# Command `polymer build` does not add certain bower_components

Tags: polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I am using the `polymer-starter-kit` project. In that I am using the `paper-toggle-button` and the `editor-icons.html` elements. When I use `polymer serve` to run my project, the toggle button and the `edit` icon are shown in the browser.
But, when I build my project using `polymer build`, these 2 components are not included in the `bower_components` folder of the build. 
Following is my `polymer.json`:

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/dekkho-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/listing_page/dekkho-listing.html",
    "src/home_page/dekkho-home.html",
    "src/home_page/dekkho-404.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/**/*",
    "images/**/*",
    "bower.json",
    "robots.txt"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js"
  ],
  "lint": {
    "rules": ["polymer-2"]
  },
  "builds": [{
    "name":"es6-supported",
    "addServiceWorker": true,
    "js": {"minify": true},
    "css": {"minify": true},
    "html": {"minify": false}
  },
    {
      "name":"es5-supported",
      "addServiceWorker": true,
      "js": {"compile":true, "minify": true},
      "css": {"minify": true},
      "html": {"minify": false}
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you include "paper-toggle-button"? in index.html?

Comment: No I included `paper-toggle-button` in one of my iron-pages.

Comment: if it's not included in entrypoint (or one of it dependencies) or shell (or one of it dependencies) or fragments (or one of it dependencies) then it will not be included in the build...

so you either have to include it somewhere there or add a fragment...
depends on your code and how you wanna use it

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help.Adding it to `fragments` in `polymer.json` worked for me.
If you could add it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `paper-toggle-button` needs to be included somewhere in your codebase or the analyzer can't find it.

If it's not included in `entrypoint` (or one of it dependencies) or `shell` (or one of it dependencies) or `fragments` (or one of it dependencies) then it will not be included in the build - as the analyzer thinks it's actually not needed.

So you either have to include it somewhere in your codebase or add it as a fragment. Depending on what fit's your need.